# How to install 'Rcpp, package? I got "package is not available"

Tags: r

I am trying to install r package 'Rccp' which is necessary for the 'caret' package. 
Running:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
```

results in:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)
```

I am using:

- Ubuntu 12.10,
- 'r ('littler') version 0.1.5 using GNU R Version
  2.13.2 (2011-09-30)'
- RStudio Version 0.98.942

How to install this package? Or maybe there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning says that Rcpp is not available for R version 2.15.1. You mention that you are using R version 2.13.2 which is even older. If you update R to a newer version it should work.

Comment: ... and while it is theoretically possible to go backwards and install older versions of Rcpp that are compatible with your version of R (see the [Rcpp package archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/)), in practice you will very rapidly descend into dependency hell.  Save yourself a huge hassle by updating R if at all possible.

Comment: I have updated R to version 3.0.1 and it works now, thanks!